# ArrayList и его тип при наследовании

Tags: java, arraylist

---

Задание: Написать программу которая будет иметь классы и они будут наследоваться.
*Animal -> Felling -> Tiger, Lion, Cat.*

---

Вопрос: В своём коде я создавал каждый конечный элемент иерархии наследования (*Tiger, Lion, Cat*) по одному экземпляру и добавлял их в *ArrayList*

```java
    ArrayList<Animals> animals = new ArrayList<>();
        animals.add(new Cat());
        animals.add(new Tiger());
        animals.add(new Lion());
```

Вот методы классов

```java
abstract public class Animals {

    abstract public void voice();

    abstract public void walk();

    abstract public void eat();
```

---

```java
abstract public class Felline extends Animals {

    abstract public void voice();

    public void walk(){
        System.out.println("Walking like a Felline");
    }

    public void eat(){
        System.out.println("Eating like a Felline");
    }

    public void sitDown(){
        System.out.println("Sitting down like a Felline");
    }
}
```

---

```java
public class Cat extends Felline{
    @Override
    public void voice(){
        System.out.println("Mew!");
    }
}
```

(В классах Tiger, Lion тоже самое что и в Cat)

Я могу получить доступ к методам класса *Animal* таким образом

```java
animals.get(i).voice();
```

Но каким образом теперь мне можно получить метод sitDown()?

---

Буду очень признателен за ответ. 3 день не могу найти решение.

Comment: `((Felline)animals.get(i)).sitDown()`, но по хорошему ещё проверку с помощью instanceof надо добавить.

Comment: Интересно, спасибо.
А как в общем объявление ArrayList<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<>();
Оно правильное в данной ситуации? или есть лучший вариант?

Answer (score 1):

В данном примере используется 2 уровня абстракции, классы: Animals (первый (высший) уровень) и его наследник Felline (второй уровень). В классе Felline добавлен новый метод `public void sitDown();`, который "не виден" в супер-классе Animals. Он об этом методе даже "не догадывается"))) Далее - при создании коллекции ArrayList ты указал, что в ней будут храниться объекты типа Animals

```
ArrayList<Animals> animals = new ArrayList<>();
```

т.е. классы, наследуемые от высшей ступени твоей иерархии абстракции (Animals - Felline - Cat,Dog,Lion), что вполне допустимо. При использовании метода `voice();` любого элемента коллекции проблем нет. Этот метод "известен" на всех уровнях абстракции. А вот с методом `sitDown();` немного сложнее. Ты указал, что тип элементов коллекции будет Animals, но на этом (высшем) уровне этот метод не виден(см.выше).

Таким образом, чтобы использовать данный метод необходимо либо явно, прямо в коде приводить к типу Felline:

```
((Felline)animals.get(i)).sitDown()
```

о чём тебе пояснил Serodv, либо поменять тип элементов при объявлении коллекции, понизить его до уровня Felline:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class AnimalTestDrive{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        ArrayList<Felline> animals = new ArrayList<>();
        animals.add(new Cat());

        animals.get(0).voice();
        animals.get(0).sitDown();       
    }
}
```

Кстати, на заметку, английское слово Feline (кошачий) пишется с одной буквой "l", но это я так, для расширения кругозора )))

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!))
И за upgrade моего английского тоже спасибо)

Comment: Да не за что, удачи!)))

Answer (score 1):

Ваш `ArrayList` может хранить либо объекты типа `Animals`, либо экземпляры его подклассов. Но в классе `Animals` отсутствует метод `sitDown()`, а значит, не все `Animals` могут обладать данным методом (а только лишь `Feline`, где вы его определили).
Следовательно, есть 2 выхода из данной ситуации:

1. Исходя из вашего кода, ваш `ArrayList` хранит лишь только экземпляры подклассов класса `Feline` (`Cat`, `Lion`, `Tiger`), а значит, изменив тип `Animals` на `Feline`, вы буквально скажите, что мой `ArrayList` будет состоять только из `Feline` и экземпляров его подклассов. Но, как было сказано выше, ваш метод `sitDown()` находится в абстрактном классе `Feline`, а значит, все его подклассы тоже имеют данный метод. Таким образом, можно просто вызвать данный метод:

   ```
   List<Feline> felines = new ArrayList<>();
   felines.sitDown();
   ```
2. Если же в вашем `ArrayList` могут быть и другие `Animals` (не `Feline`), то у них этот метод отсутствует, следовательно, нужно делать проверку `instanceof`, а также приведение типов, что накладывает дополнительные расходы и ухудшает читаемость кода.

---

#### Замечания:

- Используйте единственное число в названиях классов (если этот класс не
  является util-классом, такие как `Arrays` и т.д.);
- Программируйте к интерфейсу, а не к конкретной реализации (*принцип подстановки Барбары Лисков*):

  ```
  List<Animals> animals = new ArrayList<>()
  ```